# Check if person answers call or get voice mail using ask fast

Tags: json, communication, rpc, ask-fast

I use this api: [Ask Fast](http://docs.askfast.apiary.io/), to communicate with my customers. I use this to call my customers to update them on the status of their order. I need to know if the customer has picked up the phone, or that I have reached their voice mail. In the documentation there is no such a method. Is there a way to know this? In both the scenarios the servers gives a 200 code back.

I make this call:

url: http://api.aks-fast.com/dialoghandler/rpc

```
{
    "method": "outboundCallWithMap",
    "params": {
        "addressMap": {
            "003110xxxxxxx": "me"
        },
        "url": "my url",
        "accountID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "senderName": "me",
        "subject": "test message"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such method because the carries thinks that in both situations the phone is picked up. A work around would be to create interaction. For example: before giving the information ask the question: "I do not know if you are human can you press a button" if there is not button pressed for 10 seconds you know it is a voice mail. A way of achieving this would be:

Initial question json

```
        {
            "question_id":<some_id>,
            "question_text":"I do not know if you are human can you press a button",
            "type":" closed",
            "url":"<referral url>",
            "answers":[
                { 
                    "answer_id":<some_id>,
                    "answer_text":"Press one if you are human",
                    "callback":"The real question url"
                }
            ],
            "event_callbacks":[
                {
                    "event":"timeout",
                    "callback":"i am not a human url or leave empty if you want to hang up"
                },

            ],
            "media_properties": [
                {
                    "medium": "BROADSOFT",
                    "properties": 
                    {
                       "TIMEOUT": "10s"
                    }
            }
            ]
        }
```

Here you ask if the customer would like to respond. If this does not happen the phone will be hang up and your url with the right action will be called.

In the `TIMEOUT` you can specify how long it will take for the timeout method to be called.

Hope this helps.